# Web Scraping: Trying to retrieve all songs but it's returned lyrics of only one

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** lyrics of all song but the problem is it gives lyric of only one song.

Code Snippet:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

url = "https://www.lyrics.com/album/3769520/Now+20th+Anniversary%2C+Vol.+2"
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('strong')
name = ""
Length = len(tags)
Length = Length - 3 # because it gives extra things
newUrl = "https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/35873930/"
for index in range(1 , Length):
    SongName = tags[index].text.replace(" ","")
    FileName = tags[index].text + ".txt"
    newFetechedUrl = newUrl + SongName
#    print(newFetechedUrl)
    req1 = requests.get(newFetechedUrl)
    html1 = req1.content
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'html.parser')
    Lyrics = soup1.find_all("pre", {"id": "lyric-body-text"})
    print(Lyrics[0].text)
    req2 = requests.get(url)
    html2 = req2.content
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup2.find_all('strong')
#    print(tags[index].text.replace(" ",""))
    File = open(FileName,"w")
    File.close()
```

I want all the song from that page i dont know why it gives only first song lyrics

Comment: I think the `newUrl ` that you are using is wrong, the number `35873930` (which is in the link) is linked to the song "Toxic", the next song in the list has the id: `35873929`, which corresponds to the song "Tik Tok". I think it's easier to try and get the hyperlink of the song.

Comment: Thanks . can you suggest me the way to scrap all the songs ? @f

Comment: The table where the songs are listed has the class: `table tdata`, you can find all the `href`s in that class. Maybe try something link this: `items = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "tdata-ext"})[0].find_all('a', href=True)`. Look out though, because the artist names are also hyperlinks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` (or more accurately, using the `requests` module to ping or scrape a website) in a linear fashion, especially when using it multiple times can be slow and inefficient. I've changed your code up a bit, added multi-threading for faster execution time and made it simpler to read.

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Parse the initial 'album' website 
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')

# Find all song's links in 'album' site - these can be found under
# the 'strong' tab, and 'a' tab
links = [tag.a["href"] for tag in soup.find_all('strong')[1:-3]] 

def getLyrics(url):
    url = HOST + url # songs are found on the HOST website
    # Parse 'song' site
    req = requests.get(url)
    html = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
    # Obtain the lyrics, which can be found under the 'pre' tab
    return soup.find('pre').text

# Use multi-threading for faster performance - I'll give a small run down:
# max_workers = number of threads - we use an individual thread for each song
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(links)) as executor:
    # for every song...
    for j in range(len(links)):
        # run the 'getLyrics' method on an individual thread and get the lyrics
        lyrics = executor.submit(getLyrics, links[j]).result()
        # do whatever with the lyrics ... I simply printed them
        print(lyrics)
```

The `concurrent.futures` module gives a good interface for multi-threading, You can read more about it in it's documentation - [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed)

Of course you can still further modify it, make it even more efficient and change it according to your needs - but this should be a basic solution to your question.

Comment: Thanks alot now i have to understand this code . Actually i am new to Python thats why my code was not working <3

Comment: this works for this particular page, but I'm pretty sure it'll break on the line `links = [tag.a["href"] for tag in soup.find_all('strong')[1:-3]]` for a lot of other pages.

Comment: I just checked this code for various album links on the website, it seems to work :) @wpercy

Answer (score 1):

This code will pull all the song titles and lyrics from each page and store them in a dictionary keyed on song title:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

BASE_URL = "https://www.lyrics.com"

def get_song_and_lyrics(path):
    new_url = BASE_URL + path
    r = requests.get(new_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
    return soup.find('h1').text, soup.find('pre').text


url = BASE_URL + "/album/3769520/Now+20th+Anniversary%2C+Vol.+2"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all('strong')

song_links = []
# iterate over each song entry and grab the link to the lyrics
for s in tags:
    link = s.find('a')
    if link and link['href'].startswith('/lyric'):
        song_links.append(link['href'])

songs = {}
# then we iterate over all the lyric links and get the lyrics for each song
# those lyrics are then stored in songs[song_title]
for l in song_links:
    song,lyrics = get_song_and_lyrics(l)
    songs[song] = lyrics
```

for example:

```
print songs['Toxic']
```

will print the lyrics to Toxic

In our `get_song_and_lyrics` function, we pass in the relative path to the song's lyrics, and create a new soup object with the contents of that page. The song title is stored in the first `<h1>` element and the lyrics are in the first `<pre>` element.